# show the function is a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

> Show that $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb R, f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ is a homeomorphism.

In order for this function to be a homeomorphism it needs to be bijective and its inverse needs to exist and be continuous.

I got $f^{-1}$ to be $y=x(1-y^2)$ however I do not know if this is correct.

Comment: The definition of homeomorphism that i am using is: A continuous map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism if :
-f is bijective 
-$f^{-1} exists$ and is continuous

Comment: You are right with http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Homeomorphism and you can show that your $f$ is continuous on $(-1,1)$ easily enough. You've not found the inverse correctly. You want something of the form $g(y)$ where $f(g(y))=y$, which will also be continuous just by composition of continuous functions

Answer (score 2):

The explicit inverse is:

$$x=f^{-1}(y)=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}$$

This is gotten by using the quadratic formula to solve $y(1-x^2)=x$ or $yx^2+x-y=0$. Normally, that gives two solutions, but the solution $x=\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}$ is outside $(-1,1)$.

You have to deal with the case $y=0$ separately, of course - then $x=0$. Then you need to prove that this function is continuous. This is trivial except at $0$.

So you need to prove:
$$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y} = 0$$

Comment: thank you for help, in order to find out if the inverse is continuous would we use algebra of continuity?

Comment: I have no idea what "algebra of continuity" means. @greg

Comment: I suspect what he means is simply using theorems of continuous functions from calculus. First, the function $1+4y^2$ is continuous, and the square root function is continuous, so by composition the function $\sqrt{1+4y^2}$ is continuous. Next, the sum of continuous functions is continuous so $-1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}$ is continuous. Finally the quotient of continuous functions is continuous so $f^{-1}(y)$ is continuous. @greg

Comment: But of course this only works for $y \ne 0$.

Comment: But $f^{-1}$ is not injective, because ${y\to \infty)f^{-1}(y)={y\to -\infty}\f^{-1}(y)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate $f'(x)$ :

$$
f'(x) = \frac{(1-x^2) - x(-2x)}{(1-x^2)^2} = \frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)^2} > 0
$$
and since $\lim_{x \to -1^+} f(x) = -\infty$, $\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x) = \infty$, you conclude by the inverse function theorem that $f$ is a diffeomorphism (by this I mean a $C^1$ map with a $C^1$-inverse), hence in particular an homeomorphism.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Do you really think he knows what a diffeomorphism is, yet?

Comment: Im not sure what diffeomorphism is.

Comment: I think that as our function is a monotonic function this shows that by working out the limit we no that the function is both injective and surjective therefore proving the first property of it being bijective however i am still unsure how to work out the inverse ? If any one can help me

Comment: Yes, Patrick is using a very general theorem to prove the inverse is continuous. @greg

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : I agree it might be a sledgehammer, but I think it is okay to assume that the OP knows what differentiation means, and if he doesn't know what $C^1$ means he could have always commented but it would have indeed be nice of me to explicit it, although I didn't think of doing it in the first place.

Comment: @greg : If you can't assume the Inverse Function Theorem (or if you don't know it), then of course my proof isn't of much help. The inverse function theorem in this case says that we can define the inverse function "locally", i.e. in the neighborhood of a point $p \in (-1,1)$, say $U$, there is a neighborhood of the point $f(p) \in \mathbb R$, say $V$, such that the restriction $f : U \to V$ is differentiable with differentiable inverse. But if you want the function explicitly it doesn't bring you anywhere close to computing anything.

Comment: The problem with this sort of answer is that, by the time a person knows the inverse function theorem, this question wouldn't be asked on a homework assignment.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Sure. I totally agree on your comment, I was just not thinking it through very much at the moment and simply answered.